# How can I realise the same physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Once I saw a Google Play game where there was such
good physics. I'm new in `Rigidbody2D` move and physics. How can I do
the same physics? Now my bullet just explodes and don't boost tank. When I added `Rigidbody2D`, bullet pushed my tank 
on a little bit, but that's all, my tank stops.

[image: gif]

I have only default `Rigidbody2D` move script.

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            if (moveup1) // bool button for touch controls
            { 
                direction = Mathf.Sign(Vector2.Dot(rb.velocity, rb.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right)));
                rb.AddRelativeForce(-Vector2.left * upspeed * 300); // these vectors looks weird but all work perfectly
            }

            if (movedown1) // bool button
            {
                direction = Mathf.Sign(Vector2.Dot(rb.velocity, rb.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right)));
                rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.left * downspeed * 300);
            }

            if (rotateleft1) // bool button
            {
                steeringAmount = -1;
                rb.rotation += steeringAmount * steeringPower;
                rb.AddRelativeForce(-Vector2.right * rb.velocity.magnitude * steeringAmount / 2);
            }
            if (rotateright1) // bool button
            {
                steeringAmount = 1;
                rb.rotation += steeringAmount * steeringPower;
                rb.AddRelativeForce(-Vector2.right * rb.velocity.magnitude * steeringAmount / 2); 
            }
    }
```

Also
numbers should I put in the `Rigidbody2D` parameters? Now I'm using these params:

[image: rbparams]
[image: scriptparams]

I hope for your understanding and patience. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `Please tell me with an example.` sounds like asking for a tutorial - which is a close reason (a reason people will vote to close your question) in SO. Note - I did not downvote you.

Comment: @mjwills I mean what parameters in Rigidbody2D should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower Mass and Linear Drag. Also add Force when you instantiate the bullet. Force direction should be negative shooting direction.

If you want to push the tank on impact, the direction would be `Vector3 dir = tank.position - impact.position`. However the vector is longer on bigger distances, but we want the opposite (the close the explosion, the more force). So we can use `float force = 1f / dir.magnitude` and then apply it like this

```
rb.addForce(dir.normalized * force);
```

In general there is [Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html) but it's not available for 2D.

Comment: What is impact.posiiton?

Comment: a placeholder, you need to use the position of the projectile when it explodes.

Comment: VS underlines `normalized` in `rb.AddForce(dir.normalized() * force);`

Comment: but I don't know how to "use the position of the projectile when it explode"

Comment: how do you detect the explosion? Do you have OnTriggerEnter2D or something?

Comment: OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)

Comment: then use col.transform.position to get the projectiles position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196638/discussion-between---and-kyl3r).

Comment: KYL3R ? what happened?

Comment: sorry, just answered in chat :)

Comment: KYL3R check chat )

Comment: @Eloren I answered

Comment: KYL3R what is fwd?

Comment: just add "Vector3 " in front. see chat

Comment: tired to type here :)

Comment: KYL3R You just don't see my messages or don't recieve notifications?

Comment: I don't receive notifications for the chat. I'm in now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196819/discussion-between-eloren-and-kyl3r).

Comment: wrong chat, here real chat is https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196638/discussion-between---and-Eloren

Comment: KYL3R check chat :)